# Use a secure maven repository over https

Tags: maven, ssl

I read the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-repository-ssl.html) but I can't figure out what's wrong.

I configured my POM to declare the repository:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>snmp4j</id>
        <url>https://oosnmp.net/dist</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.snmp4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>snmp4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then I used Firefox to export the certificate. Click on the Lock -> More Information -> View Certificate -> Details -> Export ... -> snmp4j.crt

Then I imported the public key to my truststore

```
keytool -importcert -file snmp4j.crt -keystore trust.jks -alias "snmp4j"
```

The I configured maven options

```
-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=k:\home\ssl\trust.jks -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:data
```

But when I run the `mvn compile` command, the dependency is not downloaded. At least I should see the SSL debug trace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your repository URL is wrong. Try `https://oosnmp.net/dist/release`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.someorg</groupId>
<artifactId>ai</artifactId>
<version>9.9.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>snmp4j</id>
        <url>https://oosnmp.net/dist/release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories> 
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.snmp4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>snmp4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Works for me no, without SSL system properties. `mvn verify` works. Added minimal pom above